# SQL Update row with JOIN on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, sql-update

I'm making an import of data. I have a materialized tree where I want to rebuild ID numbers. 
I plan to import data from an old table to a new one, then to update the parent_id of all rows in the new table based on newly created IDS.

New table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_parent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `depth` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `old_node_Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

As you can see, in the new table I've added an additional column named old_node_id which I want to use in update. The imported data looks like in the attached screen.

[image: materialized tree browse view]

Now I want to rebuild parent ids with this query

```
UPDATE category k INNER JOIN category k2 ON k.old_node_id = k2.id_parent SET k.id_parent = k2.id
```

But there is no rows affected. Is it possible to do that? I have sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `category_name`, `category_key`, `ip`, `id_parent`, `depth`, `old_node_Id`) VALUES
(1, 'Test 1', '031', '025_026_027_031', 1382, 4, 1382),
(2, 'Test 2', '032', '025_026_027_032', 1382, 4, 1178),
(3, 'Test 3', '034', '025_026_027_034', 1382, 4, 1179);
```

Those are rows from new table. All I have to to is replace id_parent values with new IDs from id column.

Comment: in your example there is no rows matched.

Comment: It's just example. I have more rows where od_node_id and id_parent match.

Comment: please provide a fiddle example or give some example data.

Comment: Sample data is here now.

Comment: i dont know it doesnt work for you your query but it looks it works [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8330f8/1) , or maybe you want something else ?

Comment: This exacly what I want, but for all rows.

Comment: here for all rows . http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06676/1

Comment: This is the same query you gave me before.

Comment: yes but i added one row and want you to look to the results

Comment: Ok works. I don't know what I did wrong at start... Thanks.

Comment: you welcome dude. if something is wrong just debug it and see where you done wrong

Answer (score 0):

can you see the results of sql below which is used in your update statement for identifying records to be updated ...
does this returns any results?

select * from category k INNER JOIN category k2 ON k.old_node_id = k2.id_parent

this will help in finding rows which should be updated by update clause.

Comment: Yes. I have 35 results with your query. So any ideas how to update in the way I need?